# upgrading to latest NServiceBus & castle windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, nservicebus, esb

I'm trying to get to the latest of nservicebus and castle windsor:

My issue is that now the exact code that did run - no longer does:

```
var _container = new WindsorContainer();
           NServiceBus.Configure.With()
               .CastleWindsorBuilder(_container) 
               .XmlSerializer()
               .MsmqTransport()
               .UnicastBus()
                   .DoNotAutoSubscribe();
```

Yep - that's the old example code that is still in the source for 3.0

The actual code I'm trying to run is:

```
    var container = new WindsorContainer(new
XmlInterpreter("Windsor.config"));
           container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
           Configure.With()
                .Log4Net()
                .XmlSerializer()
               .CastleWindsorBuilder(container) 
               .MsmqTransport()
                    .IsTransactional(true)
                    .PurgeOnStartup(false)
               .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
               .UnicastBus()
                    .ImpersonateSender(false)
                    .LoadMessageHandlers()
               .IsTransactional(true)
               .CreateBus().Start();
```

Not much more in it but thought the extra bits might cause the
problem - even the most simple attempt at getting it started with the
windsor container makes it die a painful death.

The error is:

```
Component 89374c5e-29e5-4506-ba2e-5618fdc0d786 could not be
registered. There is already a component with that name. Did you want
to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you
specify a unique name.
```

It's not like I'm actually registerign anything so NSB must be trying to reg something twice maybe?

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in nsb/castle. Fixed on the master now

Comment: could you tap back here when you have added the fix and i'll try again :)

Comment: Nice one cheers - is this on a nuget or do i need to build from source?

Comment: Yes it is, the packages ends with *-CI